# Shifting text/data in Notepad++

Tags: hex, notepad++, timecodes

I don't even know if this is possible. I'm still fairly new to Notepad++

I'm trying to sort some captured data ready to import into an excel document I created. I have a problem with my chosen timecode stuck in the middle of a packet. So I have

```
(DA)TIME(TA) - time in the middle of data
```

I have already sorted the incredibly long string into packets and separated the timecode from the data through the use of commas so it now reads:

```
Some Data, Timecode, Rest of Data
```

Is there any command or way to move the data between the commas to the beginning of the line? - or the end but beginning would be preferable. I have looked through the Help section in Notepad++ and various other sites but I can't find anything to give a straight answer.

It would be easy if the timecode was constant but being a timecode it is incrementing by 1 or 2 at each capture point. I have also uniformly formatted the timecode (matlab format misses the 0 at the end so they now are all 123456.123456 format rather than some being 123456.12345).

Can it be done - if so how. I have programmers notepad too but much prefer Notepad++

Thanks in advance

Comment: import in excel->move column->save as csv

Comment: Didn't think of that! Knew there was a reason why I used commas to separate the timecode! Will give it a shot

Comment: All done and sorted, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

In the event someone had to do this in notepad++...

Some Data, Some Data, 123456.123456, Rest of Data, Rest of Data

```
Find   :(^.*,) ([0-9]*.[0-9]*,)(.*$)
Replace:\2 \1\3
```

123456.123456, Some Data, Some Data, Rest of Data, Rest of Data